# NestedScrollView, LinearLayout overscrolling beyond constraints

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to have three fragments appear beneath my collapsible toolbar. I have the fragments in a linear layout, inside a nested scroll view.

The fragments are appearing fine, the scrolling works(ish) and the linear layout works as expected. However the nestedscrolling scrolls way past where it needs to go, into blank space. All of it appears on top of the collapsible toolbar.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

I have tried using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">` on the NestScroll but it just hides half the list behind the collapsible toolbar and still overscrolls.

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/nestedScroll"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/overdueFrag"
                android:name="com.grove.groveone.FragmentHomeList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/dueSoonFrag"
                android:name="com.grove.groveone.FragmentHomeList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/paidFrag"
                android:name="com.grove.groveone.FragmentHomeList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[image: What we want to see.]
[image: Showing overscroll on top of collapsible toolbar]

---

Edit:

As requested, the toolbar xml.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/groveMainPurple">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout

            android:id="@+id/toolbarCollapsingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp"
            app:contentScrim="@color/groveMainPurple"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textRentPaymentTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/rent_payments"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteGroveText"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textRentalIncomeSubtitle"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textRentMonthlySum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:text="$"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteGroveText"
                    android:textSize="45dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textRentalIncomeSubtitle"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textRentPaymentTitle" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textRentalIncomeSubtitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/rental_income_this_month"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteGroveText"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textRentMonthlySum" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: please attach the xml of app bar

Comment: @Nidheesh Have added. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I changed the layout width/height of the `RecyclerView` in the resource file to `width:match_parent height:wrap_content`. These values were set to static values when I checked them.